# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Wildfly10?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

My requirements are,
1. Application URL should have http, domain name/ipaddress, no port number
2. Application need to redirected to https
3. And again port number should not be visible
4. All need to be doe in wildfly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Application URL should have http, domain name/ipaddress, no port number 
   Try configuring apache before JBoss instance
2. Application need to redirected to https
   add redirect-port="443" to http connector as follows :

   `<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>`

   - Configure https connectory in configuration file(standalone.xml/domain.xml)